# On mixing and weak mixing subalgebras of finite von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a full $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor. Consider mixing and weak mixing subfactors $B$ and $C$ of $M$. Are $B$ and $C$ full?

Comment: Can you give examples of $B$, $C$ and $M$ where this does hold? What is the simplest example of an $M$ where you do not know the answer?

Comment: See this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0169

Comment: No, I asked if *you* can give details in your question, rather than expecting other people to do all the work. Your comment also does not provide any reference to a particular section or result of the Cameron-Fang-Mukherjee paper